# How to read the previous row of a column and categorize the inputs based on the current column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to see if the value in row_1 is 0 or non-zero; and assign certain values to row_2 based on the row_2 values, if row_1 is 0.

//  If the previous row is **not** equal to 0, then return 'null' // if its equal to 0 then; if it's between 1-50 return 1 // if it is 50+ return 2, if both the previous row and the current row are 0, then return 'null' again.

```
df                         df
    val1                       val1   val2
0   5          ====>>      0   5      null
1   0          ====>>      1   0      null
2   14          ====>>     2   14     1
3   0                      3   0      null
4   70                     4   70     2
5   21                     5   21     null
```

This is very confusing to me.

Comment: *very confusing* -- Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pandas.cut` to form binned values, then mask with `where` on the shifted values:

```
df['val2'] = (pd
 .cut(df['val1'], bins=[0,1,50,np.inf], labels=[0, 1, 2])
 .where(df['val1'].shift().eq(0))
 .astype('Int64') # optional
)
```

output:

```
   val1  val2
0     5  <NA>
1     0  <NA>
2    14     1
3     0  <NA>
4    70     2
5    21  <NA>
```